# How can I model a star?

Tags: unity, lighting, graphic-effects

I'm trying to model a star in Unity, and it, sort of works, but it's not ideal. Currently, I'm using a large sphere with a self-illuminating material containing a star texture applied to it's surface, and a spotlight to create the effect of starlight, like this:

[image]

While it works, it doesn't look the greatest. I'm looking for an effect more along the lines of how [Kerbal Space Program](https://kerbalspaceprogram.com/en/) models a star:

[image]

How can I achieve this effect?

Comment: I don't know about Unity, but looks like you need to draw in an "additive" blend mode.

Comment: You could always go this direction: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/XdBSDh

Comment: You need to be much more specific and show that you have done your research. There is a plethora of information out there for star rendering. Typically, you will use a 2d camera-facing billboard to render the corona over top of your generic star. Nobody can teach you everything involved to make a realistic looking star on a SE answer. Here is a good tutorial from the Seed of Andromeda game. https://www.seedofandromeda.com/blogs/51-procedural-star-rendering . Another, rougher tutorial on reddit, but good info none-the-less https://www.seedofandromeda.com/blogs/51-procedural-star-rendering

Comment: In Unity, change the Shader of the Material to Additive (that's under the Particle submenu I think, because Additive blend mode is mostly useful on particles).

Comment: You can also check [100k stars](http://stars.chromeexperiments.com/) and [planet maker](http://planetmaker.wthr.us/#)

Comment: @FuzzyLogic You gave the same link twice.

Comment: @Shane Two yrs later but better late than never I guess. Cheers.. https://www.reddit.com/r/gamedev/comments/33xuyj/procedural_star_rendering/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

- Use an animated texture.* There are some good ones in the store for < $10.
- Add a Halo. You can use the particle system, or just a transparent glow texture on a billboard in front of the sun with a script to re-position the texture when the camera moves. This hides the aliased edges of the sphere model, allowing you to use a lower poly model, and looks nice.
- Rotate the sun, slowly.
- Use particle system for eruptions.
- Use a custom shader to make the edges match well with the halo(multiply normal with camera vector to find edges).

The animated gif shows a static texture first, followed by a number of additions, in order:

1. Animated Texture
2. Brighten the edges of the sphere based on normals
3. Add camera-facing transparent billboard with white/yellow halo
4. Particles, moving from the center to the outside, then fading
5. Add 2 transparent "ray" billboards, facing the camera and rotating along the camera axis in opposite directions.

[image: Building a Sun]

With the animated texture, be sure to use mipmaps, or it will look horrible at some distances. Slow framerates in the texture (10 fps) are fine when looking at a sun from far away, but when you get close, you may also want to use a higher framerate. If you don't have a high framerate texture or can't waste the video memory for one, you can use a custom shader to interpolate every other pixel based on the previous and next image.

By changing use of Hue/Saturation/Value inside the shader, you can get results like these, without ever having to modify the texture:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image: [enter image description here]
[image]

I started with a cheap model from the store so I didn't have to do the animated texture. On the other hand it means I can't share the current prefab, because the texture is purchased.

---

*Alternatively, you can look into [mapping 2D noise on a sphere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555076/how-can-i-generate-perlin-noise-on-a-spherical-surface) and use 3D noise for the time dimension, or use 4D noise if you don't want to do the mapping and can spare the performance.

Comment: If you aim for it being realistic: the edges of a star actually are not brighter but *less bright* than the centre of the disk.

Comment: @planetmaker Absolutely. But a cool looking effect is easier to achieve with a white or white-ish halo and details in the center. It can be done the other way, but I think it's quite a bit trickier Anyway, looking into a realistic sun permanently blinds us, so we don't want a realistic sun:)

Answer (score 10):

Other then the particale system and halo effects Vadim mentioned you could create your own shader effect. There is some [introduction to shaders for Unity](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ShadersOverview.html) and the possibilities are [endless](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4dXGR4).

Comment: I don't know if you found or created that shader, but it is absolutely gorgeous.

Comment: No I have not created the shader, unfortunately my knowledge about shaders is pretty basic. But I agree, it's gorgeous ;).

Answer (score 2):

Try using a Particle System and a halo effect. You could also add a light to the star and have a bloom effect on your camera.